# Centered grid menu for two textual buttons

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, interface

I'm trying to understand what is the pros and cons for the kind of menu **(Centered grid menu with two textual buttons)**.This is my main menu:

[image]

**I have only two options, with a static font size of 17 points.**

**Does increasing the size of the buttons,while keeping the same font size, would be a good idea? Tho it will decrease the focus on the text it self.**

**But keeping at the of the button like this, would create big space between them.**

**What would you suggest? Thank you!**

Comment: First, this is not a menu, but 2 buttons. Second, get those 2 buttons together, they're options of a main process and this layout is really confusing. Anyways, the spacing part belongs to  http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ and its connection with UX is more related to further testing

Comment: @Devin , Hey Devin! Thank you for responding! So either way, does button should be close, In your opinion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! The buttons have to be close to each other and vertically center aligned. And move the settings icon to header.

Here's a quick edit -

**EDIT:**

Also the 'What would you like to do' text should behave as a title in the page, so, keep it above the buttons in a little large font.

[image]

Comment: Hey Dipak! Thank you for answering. A few questions if i may: 1. In my next screens, the text at the navigation is centered. Is it still okay to place it at the lefty side? 2. For different screen sizes, the the button container size changes? Or it's static size? Thank you!

Comment: @RoiMulia If you keep the text inside navigation center aligned or left aligned doesn't matter much. Just maintain the consistency on all screens.  As per the principles of Responsive Designing, the buttons size must change for different devices.

Comment: I think i will remove the settings button and center the text(as you said), does the font size should change as well?(if the button grows bigger)

Comment: @RoiMulia Yes! Check the edited image.

Comment: If we are removing the settings icon completely, won't it be better to put the text at the navigation? :)